# LSTM Time Series Forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, python, multivariate-analysis, lstm, keras

I am working with Bitcoin block data and attempting to forecast target hashrate ~one month in advance.  I have condensed the raw block-by-block data into daily data and calculating metrics like average block time, fastest and slowest N blocks / transaction fees / etc... per day, and then further condensed that into a smaller timeseries that averages the values per epoch (i.e. ~14 days) so we have roughly only 230 datapoints, where the first epoch begins at the end of 2012 and each datapoint is ~14 days apart.

I am attempting to implement an LSTM model to forecast using this guide:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/

using 4 timestep lag (~2 months).  I am a complete newbie to ML, and wanted to ask for opinions on whether it sounds like I'm heading in the right direction, or if this is a problem I will likely make no progress on.  If this is a viable problem to try solving, then what suggestions / corrections do you have to my methodology?  I am aware the guide does not forecast - it only uses $t-1..t-N$ to predict $t$, and was going to attempt further forecasts after achieving something decent for $t$.  I would also like to ask- if I am forecasting only the target hashrate, is there a need to include other variable shifted timesteps $t...t+N$ in the data sets, i.e. will leaving things like transaction fees in the forecast steps matter? I currently have every variable except target hashrate removed for the forecast sequence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Let me know if you need more details or clarification.